# linux mint very slow boot and authorization

Tags: linux-mint, boot, bios, authorization

I installed linux Mint. But it's booting too slow (20-30 seconds). Even during authorization it takes 3-5 seconds. Windows, for example, loaded for 5 seconds max. (I have an SSD and mint was also installed on the SSD)

During installation, the disk was divided into root and home directory. Maybe it is a problem?

I have not old computer with Intel CPU and system on SSD. Why?

Some system information:

```
$ inxi -Fxz
```

```
System:
  Host: oldcat-GL502VMK Kernel: 4.15.0-72-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.4 Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina 
  base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: GL502VMK v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: GL502VMK v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends 
  v: GL502VMK.300 date: 12/27/2016 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 54.0 Wh condition: 54.0/64.4 Wh (84%) model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery 
  status: Not charging 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-7700HQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 44928 
  Speed: 1600 MHz min/max: 800/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1322 2: 1482 3: 1442 
  4: 1448 5: 1464 6: 1303 7: 1306 8: 1442 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia 
  v: 435.21 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 01:00.1 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-72-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: e000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK 
  driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus ID: 04:00.0 
  IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.08 TiB used: 37.12 GiB (1.7%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Micron model: 1100 MTFDDAV256TBN size: 238.47 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS721010A9E630 size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM035-1RK172 size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-4: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: Patriot model: Patriot Memory size: 29.53 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 48.18 GiB used: 32.75 GiB (68.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
  ID-2: /home size: 170.16 GiB used: 2.12 GiB (1.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 62.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 47 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 255 Uptime: 2m Memory: 15.62 GiB used: 715.1 MiB (4.5%) Init: systemd 
  runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.4.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.32
```

System boot time info (I was very confused, because in fact it lasted about 30 seconds):

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
```

```
          1.209s ufw.service
          1.209s ufw.service
          1.113s dev-sda3.device
           730ms snapd.service
           401ms dev-loop1.device
           400ms dev-loop2.device
           382ms dev-loop3.device
           366ms systemd-logind.service
           360ms systemd-resolved.service
           358ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           356ms dev-loop4.device
           354ms dev-loop5.device
           314ms dev-loop6.device
           288ms dev-loop7.device
           242ms NetworkManager.service
           182ms snap-core18-1279.mount
           155ms lightdm.service
           154ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           148ms snap-snap\x2dstore-209.mount
           137ms udisks2.service
           134ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           121ms snap-snapd-5754.mount
           115ms dev-loop0.device
           114ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1353.mount
           103ms networkd-dispatcher.service
            93ms snap-core-8268.mount
            90ms ubuntu-system-adjustments.service
            88ms ModemManager.service
            83ms accounts-daemon.service
            83ms systemd-udevd.service
            81ms snap-discord-101.mount
            80ms upower.service
            77ms thermald.service
            76ms grub-common.service
            75ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-98.mount
            74ms hddtemp.service
            72ms bluetooth.service
            68ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            66ms avahi-daemon.service
            60ms systemd-rfkill.service
            60ms keyboard-setup.service
            59ms lvm2-monitor.service
            55ms systemd-journald.service
            54ms lm-sensors.service
            54ms gpu-manager.service
            53ms alsa-restore.service
            52ms apparmor.service
            40ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount
            34ms user@1000.service
            34ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-921E\x2dB74C.service
            28ms speech-dispatcher.service
            26ms wpa_supplicant.service
            24ms networking.service
            19ms snapd.seeded.service
            19ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a9415c58\x2d0de0\x2d438e\x2d867e\x2d3aa8
            18ms systemd-modules-load.service
            17ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            16ms colord.service
            12ms home.mount
            12ms kerneloops.service
            12ms pppd-dns.service
            12ms plymouth-start.service
            12ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            12ms nvidia-persistenced.service
            11ms dev-mqueue.mount
            11ms plymouth-read-write.service
            11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            10ms rsyslog.service
             9ms polkit.service
             8ms systemd-sysctl.service
             7ms ureadahead-stop.service
             7ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             6ms boot-efi.mount
             6ms systemd-remount-fs.service
             5ms dns-clean.service
             4ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             4ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms console-setup.service
             3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             3ms blk-availability.service
             3ms dev-hugepages.mount
             3ms systemd-backlight@backlight:nvidia_0.service
             3ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service
             2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             2ms openvpn.service
             2ms systemd-random-seed.service
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             1ms setvtrgb.service
             1ms snapd.socket
```

After all, even during authorization, if the password is not correct it quickly says that, but when it is correct the system sags (orange flickers once) and after 5 seconds the desktop is displayed.

System shutdown is also long (15+ seconds)